# How to ground an amplifier without ground pins on outlet?

Tags: receptacle, grounding

My electric guitar amplifier's plug has got ground pins but my wall outlet does not have any ground pin and I want to use this amplifier grounded. How could I ground this properly and safely If there is no grounded outlet in room?

Wall outlet looks like this (no ground pin):

[image]

Comment: What country is this -  and is it in town or countryside?

Comment: Greece, town...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this will get a much better response if moved to DIY.SE

Comment: Do you have any grounded receptacles in your house?

Comment: Hi, Yes I do have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Safely" is the problem.

The only way to correctly earth it would be to run a wire literally to ground somewhere - actual earth, using a large metal spike into the bare ground, to an established bonded earth, or to already grounded piping [**do not** do this if you are even slightly uncertain as to whether your building's piping is all correctly bonded to earth already.]

That is really not a DIY task.

If you live in a country that doesn't have compulsory earthing, you need a professional to install correct earthing. I would seriously never recommend this as a DIY project. If no-one bothered to earth the sockets [because code doesn't insist you must] then you have no guarantee that anything in the building is correctly earthed.

Comment: One might well ask if the OP's amp was sold configured for Greek electric systems,and if so how/why he doesn't have grounded outlets in his house.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - the thing about EU plugs is that the earth is recessed & will fit earthed & non-earthed sockets alike. There's a good answer at Quora which shows how they will fit either type - https://www.quora.com/Why-dont-European-plugs-have-earth-wires